# How to parse JSON (key ,value) String on the UI side in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

I am using ReactJs on UI side and after making an ajax call to backend service the response I get is a JSON string like the one below,can anyone tell me how to parse it into key value pair again in UI code.

{name=xyz, transit_To=INIT, request=something, Skip=true, action=Submit , Priority=1, Node=Submit}

How can i access the key value pairs as this is a string.

Any sort of information would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

*Proper* JSON can be parsed using JSON.parse. Eg.,

```
const options = JSON.parse('{"name":"xyz","transit_To":"INIT",  ...}');
```

Your example string does not appear to be proper JSON, and thus you probably have to write a custom parser, if you have no control over the backend API.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON syntax, so assuming you're getting valid JSON back:

```
$ const parsed_json = JSON.parse('{"name":"xyz","transit_To":"INIT"}');
// Object {name: "xyz", transit_To: "INIT"}

$ parsed_json.name
// "xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

"When you get a JSON string in response, *do not look at it."*   Instead, treat it as “an *opaque(!)* piece of information,” and pass it **directly** to `JSON.parse()`.

*If* the parse succeeded, then what you now have in your hands is:   “a JavaScript data structure.” In this case, it will be an object (or a hash) with *keys* such as `name`, `transit_To`, and so on. Which you can now treat as you would any such JavaScript thing, regardless of where it came from.